# 301 redirects along with URL rewriting to reduce URLs with query params

Tags: iis, iis-7, rewrite, 301-redirect

Okay, so I have URL rewriting set up on my server (IIS 7) so that, for example,

```
http://example.org/p/1234/
```

is really

```
http://example.org/product/?product_id=1234
```

(With /product/ containing an index file for a web app that's able to process the query params).

The problem is, I want *everyone* to use the `/p/1234/` urls now, so I'd like to send a 301 redirect whenever someone visits the *old* url of `/product/?product_id=1234`, **but** as far as I can tell when URL rewriting occurs, as far as the server is concerned the user *did* go to `/product/?product_id=1234`.

Although in the browser's URL bar it may say `http://example.org/p/1234/`, when I do a dump of headers and CGI variables, `/p/1234/` doesn't show up in *any* of the variables.

I guess my concern is, even if I can do this, it seems like it would make a simple request fairly convoluted:

1. Go to `/p/1234/`
2. Rewrite it to `/product/?product_id=1234`
3. Was it originally `/p/1234/`? (*yes*)
4. Do nothing.

And otherwise:

1. Go to `/product/?product_id=1234`
2. Was it originally `/p/1234/`? (*no*)
3. 301 Redirect to `/p/1234/`
4. Rewrite it to `/product/?product_id=1234`
5. Was it originally `/p/1234/`? (*yes*)
6. Do nothing.

I know that eventually some search indexes will eliminate the old URLs in favor of the ones specified by the 301 redirect, but until then it seems like a lot of overhead for the servers.

Also, if I did set this up, is there a filter I could use in IIS to do this, or would I need to add the logic to my webapp?

Note that I have set up `<link rel="canonical".../>` for all of these webpages but I still see the old format showing up in search results.

Comment: Just did another dump of the headers and it appears that IIS does make them available under a proprietary header `X-Original-URL`. Still curious about the impact of using 301 redirects in this case.

Comment: ***crickets*** ***crickets***